# Differential equation in chemical reaction

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

What kind of differential equation is the following?
$$
y'=k(a-y)(b-y), \qquad y(0) = 0
$$

I suppose that it is a [Bernoulli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_differential_equation) differential equation, but am not sure.

Comment: It's Riccati's differential equation [Riccati](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riccati_equation). It's not a Bernoulli equation, because we have a constant term

Comment: how solve Riccati`s differential equation?

Comment: This differential equation is classical and known under the name "logistic differential equation".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$y'=k(a-y)(b-y), \qquad y(0) = 0$$ is separable.

$$ \frac {dy}{(a-y)(b-y)} = kdx$$

Integrate using partial fraction and solve for $y$.